# Remove all letters from input value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a button that clears an `input type='text'` from all its letters. I want it to, when clicked, remove all characters except numbers and commas.

```
<input type="text" id="txt" value="1a,2b,3c">
<input type="button" id="reml" value="Remove Letters" onclick="???????">
```

I was thinking it would be something like:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('reml').value.replace(a[],'');

a = ['a','b','c',etc.];
```

But I'm not sure if something like that'd work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a jsFiddle with a targeted example. https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/f6r71z7o/  It looks like you know you need to use regex, so outline what you've tried and what you think the issue may be a bit more clearly.

Comment: *"But I'm not sure if something like that'd work..."* - So actually trying it was more trouble than posting here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines.

```js
function clearInvalid() {
  var input = document.getElementById('txt')
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d,]/g,'')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" value="1a,2b,3c">
<input type="button" id="reml" value="Remove Letters" onclick="clearInvalid()">
```

Comment: this removes the decimal places, any way around that?

Comment: oh wait I just added a dot to it so it was replace(/[^\d,.]/g,'')

Comment: @FinleySherwood Haha, classic!

Answer (score 1):

Make this the `onclick` code:

```
var theinput = document.getElementById('reml')
theinput.value = theinput.value.replace(/[^\d,]/g,'')
```

This uses a regex to find all non-digit and comma characters and replaces them with an empty string

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like the following one to transform the text:

```
function transform(s) {
    var out = "";
    for (var index = 0; index < s.length; ++index) {
        if ((!isNaN(s[index])) || (s[index] === ',')) {
            out += s[index];
        }
    }
    return out;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to do this, and jQuery can make your code even shorter:

```html
<html>
<input type="text" id="txt" value="1a,2b,3c">
<input type="button" id="reml" value="Remove Letters">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $("#reml").on("click", function(event) {
  $("#txt").val($("#txt").val().replace(/[^\d,]/g, ''));
 });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Puzzled by the quest for shorter code by adding 10,000+ lines of library.